# Update sql table using if statements

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update my table called user_results using an 'if' statement based on data that I have stored in another table.  A bit of background: Users are making their weekly picks(game1, game2 etc) and I want to match the picks up with the results to see whether points should be awarded.  If they got the pick right, the amount of points they bet will be awarded (points1, points2 etc) and all of it will be updated in the user_results table in column week1.

Here is an example of the week1_picks table:

```
username     game1             points1     game2             points2
jake25    New England Patriots   4      Green Bay Packers     5
test24    Pittsburgh Steelers    1      Chicago Bears         1
```

Here's what the nfl_schedule table looks like:

```
 game  away                    home                      winner
 1   Pittsburgh Steelers  New England Patriots   New England Patriots
 2   Green Bay Packers      Chicago Bears        Green Bay Packers
```

To try and test part of it just to get something to work, I tried this:

```
update user_results
    if user_week1_picks.game1 = New England Patriots then
        set week1 = points1 
        where username = user_results.username; 
else 
    set week1 = 0
    where username = user_results.username;
```

I keep getting an error saying: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if user_week1_picks.game1 = New England Patriots then
        set week1 = points1 
' at line 2

My desired outcome is that all of the weekly scores for players are computed through this query so it would look something like this:

```
username week1 week2
jake25     9     0
test24     0     0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Was there a question in there? Or were you providing a status report?*

MySQL is returning that particular error because the syntax of the SQL text is (in fact) not valid, according the MySQL Reference Manual.

Reference: [MySQL Reference Manual 13.2.11 UPDATE Syntax  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html)

---

To perform an operation like you seem to be describing, you would use syntax like this:

```
  UPDATE user_results r
     SET r.week1 = expr
   WHERE r.username = 'yosemite sam'
```

Where the expression `expr` can make use of (valid) MySQL syntax, including the `IF()` function, or a more ANSI standard `CASE` expression.

But it looks like you want to reference values of columns from other tables. To do that, you might be able to make use of a subquery, but it looks more like you'd want to use the multi-table form of the UPDATE statement.

The easiest way to get to that is to write a SELECT statement that returns the column you want to update, and an expression that returns the new value you want to assign.

To get the game1 results, something like this:

```
  SELECT r.username
       , r.week1
       , IF(s1.winner=p1.game1, p1.points1, 0) AS week1_newval
    FROM user_results r
    LEFT JOIN nfl_schedule s1  ON s1.game = 1 
    LEFT JOIN week1_picks  p1  ON p1.username = r.username
```

You also want to get the game2, game3, etc. results. The SQL to that is going to be more involved, mostly because the `week1_picks` table doesn't have separate rows for each game (1, 2)... and you want to get a total.  So we have to accommodate that with more complicated SQL.  There's a couple of ways we can approach doing that. But we'll skip that discussion for now.

To turn that SELECT statement into a multi-table UPDATE, we replace the `SELECT ... FROM` with the `UPDATE` keyword, and add a `SET` clause to assign the result of the expression to the column we want to update.

For example:

```
  UPDATE user_results r
    LEFT JOIN nfl_schedule s1  ON s1.game = 1 
    LEFT JOIN week1_picks  p1  ON p1.username = r.username
     SET r.week1 = IF(s1.winner=p1.game1, p1.points1, 0)
```

That's just an example of how we convert a `SELECT` statement into an `UPDATE` statement.  Writing it as a `SELECT` statement first lets us return the rows we're going to update, the current value, and what the new value we are going to assign. That lets us see whats going on, and helps us develop the query conditions and expressions to get the results we want.

---

The `SELECT` statement you need is going to be more involved than that simple example, because you are wanting to check multiple games. To get a total points, we can use a `GROUP BY` clause, and a `SUM()` aggregate, and we're likely going to want to do that in an inline view... something along the lines of:

```
  SELECT r.username
    FROM user_results r
    JOIN ( SELECT p.username
                , s.game
                , r.week1
                , SUM( 
                    CASE s.game
                    WHEN  1 THEN IF(p.game1=s.winner,p.points1,0) 
                    WHEN  2 THEN IF(p.game2=s.winner,p.points2,0)
                    WHEN  3 THEN IF(p.game3=s.winner,p.points3,0)
                    WHEN  4 THEN IF(p.game4=s.winner,p.points4,0)
                    ELSE 0 
                    END
                  ) AS total_earned_points 
             FROM week1_picks p 
             LEFT
             JOIN nfl_schedule s
           GROUP BY p.username
         ) q
      ON q.username = r.username 
   ORDER BY r.username
```

Comment: Yes there was a question in there and thanks for the reply.  I guess it's a lot more complicated than I thought it would be. For the last part, it looks like it will run until the GROUP BY part where I get a syntax error.  Any idea? Looks like I have my work cut out for me to get a good understanding of sql and how to run this query.  Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: The last SELECT query was an illustration of one way to go about getting "total points" by username, but it has some problems. The `LEFT` keyword can be omitted., there's no need for that to be an outer join, and there's no join predicate. So the `LEFT` keyword could be replaced with the `CROSS` keyword, indicating each row in `week1_picks` matches every row in `nfl_schedule (a "cross product" of the two tables).  Also. the `r.week1` in the SELECT list is invalid, and should be removed. And the `s.game` should be removed. First write the query to return individual rows, get that working

Comment: and tested, verify the results.  Then starting from that, you can add in the GROUP BY and the SUM() aggregate to get the individual rows collapsed into a single row (by username), and return a total from the collapsed set of rows. If you are just learning SQL, then I would recommend you start working out queries for some simpler questions, before tackling the "calculate total points" question.  (That problem is complicated by the design of the tables. It would be simpler if the `week1_picks` table was normalized, with a separate row for each game, and a single "prediction" and "points" column.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot for your help!  I will look into normalizing the tables to make the query easier.